# Trying to access array offset value of type bool al hacer un insert en mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Me da el siguiente error a la hora de insertar el registro, y lo más curioso es que el insert va, pero falla a la hora de comprobar el nombre y el email, en la consulta select, pego las capturas y el codigo, le he dado mil vueltas hasta poniendo is_null en las row y nada.
Un saludo gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="front_end/Bootstrap_5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="front_end/font_awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="front_end/style.css">
    <title>Registrarse</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light menu-fonts">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="acceso.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Acceder
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="registro.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Registrarse
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto col-lg-5">
                <h1 class="my-5 text-center titulos-forms">Pantalla de Registro</h1>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <?php
                    require_once 'back_end/conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';

                    if (isset($_POST['btn_registrar'])) 
                    {
                        $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
                        $email = $_POST['email']; 
                        $password = $_POST['password']; 
                        

                        if (empty($nombre)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese nombre de usuario";
                        } else if (empty($email)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese email";
                        } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese email valido";
                        } else if (empty($password)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese password"; 
                        } else if (strlen($password) < 3) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Password minimo 3 caracteres"; 
                        } else {
                            try {
                                $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                $select_stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT nombre, email FROM usuarios WHERE nombre=:nombre OR email=:email"); // consulta sql
                                $select_stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
                                $select_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
                                $select_stmt->execute();
                                // $select_stmt->debugDumpParams();
                                //var_dump($select_stmt->errorInfo());
                                $row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                 var_dump($row);
                                 var_dump($bd->errorInfo());


                                if ($row["nombre"] == $nombre) {
                                    $errorMsg[] = "El Usuario ya existe"; 
                                } else if ($row["email"] == $email) {
                                    $errorMsg[] = "El Email ya existe"; 
                                } else if (!isset($errorMsg)) {
                                    $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                    var_dump($bd->errorInfo());
                                    $insert_stmt = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,email,password) VALUES(:nombre,:email,:password)"); //Consulta sql de insertar 
                                    $insert_stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
                                    $insert_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
                                    $insert_stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
                                    

                                    if ($insert_stmt->execute()) {
                                        $registerMsg = "Registro exitoso: Esperar página de inicio de sesión"; //Ejecuta consultas 
                                        // header("refresh:2; acceso.php");
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                //debuguear la sentencia select
                                
                                //$select_stmt->debugDumpParams();
                                //var_dump($row);
                                
                            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>
                <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light my-5" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" aria-label="password" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                    </div>
                    <input class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn_registrar" value="Registrarse">
                    <hr class="my-4">
                    <small class="text-muted texto-para-verificar">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($errorMsg)) {
                            foreach ($errorMsg as $error) {
                        ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>INCORRECTO ! <?php echo $error; ?></strong>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                        }
                        if (isset($registerMsg)) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <strong>EXITO ! <?php echo $registerMsg; ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </small>
                </form>
                <?php
                

                if ($bd == true) {
                    echo "<p class='text-center estado-de-la-conexion'>
                            Aplicación conectada. <i class='fa fa-check-circle text-success' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                          </p>";
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer style="background-color: #ffede7;" id="bajar-footer-forms-registro">
        <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
            © 2020 Copyright:
            <a class="text-dark" href="#porftolio">D.Milanés</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
    </footer>
    <script src="front_end/Bootstrap_5/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="front_end/Bootstrap_5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Edito el var_dump del select y parece que si lo muestra cuando existe pero no cuando lo inserta

```
array(2) { ["nombre"]=> string(4) "pepe" ["email"]=> string(14) "pepe@gmail.com" }
```

Al final lo he resuelto, con un simple WHILE y PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, pego el código y marco como resuelto.
Al final ha sido mas fácil de lo que creia, lo que hace el while, es recorrer las filas con la propiedad fetch_assocc y recorrer la fila encontrando así el resultado, se pueden usar tanto bindValue como bindParam,
También he cambiado los parámetros de la sentencia a unombre,uemail, por si daba conflicto, aunque esto en los parámetros creo que da igual pero por si acaso. Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda, me ha sido muy útil !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="front_end/Bootstrap_5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="front_end/font_awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="front_end/style.css">
    <title>Registrarse</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light menu-fonts">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="acceso.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Acceder
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="registro.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Registrarse
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto col-lg-5">
                <h1 class="my-5 text-center titulos-forms">Pantalla de Registro</h1>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <?php
                    session_start();
                    require_once 'back_end/conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';
                    if (isset($_POST['btn_registrar'])) {
                        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];

                        if (empty($nombre)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese nombre de usuario";
                        } else if (empty($email)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese email";
                        } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese email valido";
                        } else if (empty($password)) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Ingrese password";
                        } else if (strlen($password) < 3) {
                            $errorMsg[] = "Password minimo 3 caracteres";
                        } else {
                            try {

                                $select_stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT nombre,email FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :unombre OR email = :uemail");
                                $select_stmt->bindValue(":unombre", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $select_stmt->bindValue(":uemail", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $select_stmt->execute();

                                // $select_stmt->debugDumpParams();

                                while ($row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $row['nombre'];
                                    $row['email'];
                                } 
                                
                                if (!isset($errorMsg)) {
                                    $insert_stmt = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,email,password) VALUES(:nombre,:email,:password)");
                                    $insert_stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
                                    $insert_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
                                    $insert_stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);

                                    if ($insert_stmt->execute()) {
                                        $registerMsg = "Registro exitoso: Esperar página de inicio de sesión";
                                        header("refresh:3; acceso.php");
                                    }
                                }
                                //$select_stmt->debugDumpParams();
                                //var_dump($row);

                            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
                </p>
                <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light my-5" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña...">
                    </div>
                    <input class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn_registrar" value="Registrarse">
                    <hr class="my-4">
                    <small class="text-muted texto-para-verificar">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($errorMsg)) {
                            foreach ($errorMsg as $error) {
                        ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>INCORRECTO ! <?php echo $error; ?></strong>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                        }
                        if (isset($registerMsg)) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <strong>EXITO ! <?php echo $registerMsg; ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </small>
                </form>
                <?php


                if ($bd == true) {
                    echo "<p class='text-center estado-de-la-conexion'>
                            Aplicación conectada. <i class='fa fa-check-circle text-success' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                          </p>";
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer style="background-color: #ffede7;" id="bajar-footer-forms-registro">
        <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
            © 2020 Copyright:
            <a class="text-dark" href="#porftolio">D.Milanés</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
    </footer>
    <script src="front_end/Bootstrap_5/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="front_end/Bootstrap_5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de las líneas 72 y 74? Y por cierto, ¿es correcta la sintaxis `header("refresh:2;acceso.php");`?

Comment: Sí es correcto el header, refresca la página cada 2 segundos y lo envía al acceso.php que es el login de acceder a la aplicación.
Estas son las líneas  72 y 74.

if ($row["nombre"] == $nombre) {
                                    $errorMsg[] = "El Usuario ya existe"; 
                                } else if ($row["email"] == $email) {
                                    $errorMsg[] = "El Email ya existe"; 
                                }

Comment: Tengo un par de dudas, puedes entrar a este chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130936/david-milanes

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *var_dump del select*? Como bien dice @Excorpion, debes depurar tu variable `$row`, mediante `var_dump($row);`, pues parece que esa es la variable que está teniendo problemas. Aparte de eso te recomiendo que renuncies a un estilo de programación optimista o ingenuo, que revises todo aquello que pueda fallar.

Comment: @A.Cedano El ultimo edit de la publicacion es cuando añadió ese var_dump(), y si trae datos, pero hay cosas extrañas aun.

Comment: Ahora los vi. La otra pregunta iba a que la sintaxis que suele verse es `header("refresh:2;url=acceso.php");` (nótese el `url=`).

Comment: @Excorpion no creo que ese sea el resultado del `var_dump`  de `$row`, los Warning mencionados en la pregunta ocurrirían únicamente si `$row` fuese un booleano.

Comment: Estamos en el chat ahora mismo viendo eso. @A.Cedano

Comment: Tiene un error en su busqueda?  La ha intentado en MySQL todavía?

Comment: @DavidMilanes: si lograste solucionarlo, ¡ponlo como respuesta! No edites tu pregunta. Y, transcurrido el tiempo mínimo, [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas invertir la lógica, porque [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-returnvalues) puede devolver falso en vez de un arreglo u objeto:

> **Valores devueltos**: El valor de retorno de esta función en caso de éxito depende del tipo de obtención. En todos los casos, se devuelve false en caso de error.

En este caso, el error se produciría cuando no se encuentran resultados y tratas de leerlos.

Entonces, podrías comparar si `$row === false` o, mejor aún, usar [rowCount()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) para saber si la consulta encontró resultados:

```
            $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $select_stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT nombre, email FROM usuarios WHERE nombre=:nombre OR email=:email"); // consulta sql
            $select_stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
            $select_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
            $select_stmt->execute();

            // Analizar total de resultados
            if($select_stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
                // No hay resultados, puedes continuar
                $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $insert_stmt = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,email,password) VALUES(:nombre,:email,:password)"); //Consulta sql de insertar 
                $insert_stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
                $insert_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
                $insert_stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);

                if ($insert_stmt->execute()) {
                    $registerMsg = "Registro exitoso: Esperar página de inicio de sesión"; //Ejecuta consultas 
                    // Redirigir
                    header("Location: acceso.php");
                    // Finalizar script
                    exit;
                }
                // Algo falló, debes mostrar mensaje de error
                $errorMsg[] = 'No se pudo insertar usuario.';
            } else {
                // Sí hay resultados, debes recorrer para verificar ambos campos
                while($row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    if ($row["nombre"] == $nombre) {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El Usuario ya existe"; 
                    } else if ($row["email"] == $email) {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El Email ya existe";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Supongo que estás trabajando en un servidor local con un búfer de salida que te permite crear sesiones y enviar encabezados después de haber enviado salida HTML. Cuando pongas esto en servidor de producción, seguramente vas a tener problemas con `headers already sent`.

Para evitarlo, solo coloca `session_start();` y todo el código de verificación / inserción al inicio del script.

### Edición importante

De acuerdo a lo mencionado por @A.Cedano en comentarios, algunos motores de base de datos podrían no obtener el total de filas correctamente. La opción es muy simple, leer todos los resultados con [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) y contar en el arreglo resultante:

```
            $select_stmt->execute();
            // Leer todas las filas de la consulta
            $rows = $select_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Analizar total de resultados
            if(count($rows) == 0) {
                // No hay resultados, puedes continuar
                $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $insert_stmt = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,email,password) VALUES(:nombre,:email,:password)"); //Consulta sql de insertar 
                $insert_stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
                $insert_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
                $insert_stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);

                if ($insert_stmt->execute()) {
                    $registerMsg = "Registro exitoso: Esperar página de inicio de sesión"; //Ejecuta consultas 
                    // Redirigir
                    header("Location: acceso.php");
                    // Finalizar script
                    exit;
                }
                // Algo falló, debes mostrar mensaje de error
                $errorMsg[] = 'No se pudo insertar usuario.';
            } else {
                // Sí hay resultados, debes recorrer para verificar ambos campos
                // Solo se cambia while por foreach
                foreach($rows as $row) {
                    if ($row["nombre"] == $nombre) {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El Usuario ya existe"; 
                    } else if ($row["email"] == $email) {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El Email ya existe";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nooop, el Manual de PHP es muy claro con respecto a `rowCount()`. Dice que NO debería confiarse en él para consultas del tipo `SELECT`. Del propio enlace que indicas en la respuesta: *"Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement asociado fue una sentencia SELECT, algunas bases de datos podrían devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo, este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables."*

Comment: @A.Cedano, se agradece el comentario y voy a editar la respuesta para agregar otra opción. Sin embargo, yo lo he usado sin inconvenientes con MySQL y habría que ver cuáles (motores de) bases de datos son los que pudieran tener ese problema.